# Clicking a Non Existent DOM item

Tags: automated-testing, browser-automation, c#, web-application, selenium-webdriver

EDIT: I used mouse events and did get a working solution that is pretty ugly :).

So I may be at a point that automating this page will not be possible. I am trying to click a popup menu that appears upon clicking an image (arrow). The problem is once I click the arrow, the popup menu does not exist anywhere that I can find. I cannot inspect its element either. It crashes the "inspect element" in IE (page must load in IE) and a using a third party extension DebugBar also does nothing.

Whats happening is that in some cases when I select the popup link it opens in a new frame on the same page. The javascript changes everything for the new frame. When it instead uses a new URL (pop up window) I won't have problems navigating. Only when I need the new frame to appear so that I can get the new elments on the page.

[image: A brief picture of the menu.]

I am wondering if anyone have any ideas I could try.

To click the arrow I have to navigate the DOM using an Xpath as the id does not exist. (the "import" icon is a button separate from the arrow) Maybe there is something I can do with calling javascript in the source?

I know the target in many places is the UCF_Mainframe. Just most of the changes happen in the javascript (which I can view all the functions by viewing source). What I believe is happening is the popup is all javascript rendered so its probably just an onclick event.

The main body:

```
<TD id=import title="Import" class=clsHeaderItem selectedImg="x" unselectedImg="null" targetArgument="" target="UCF_X" url="" dataFrame="null" popUp="0">

<TABLE style="TABLE-LAYOUT: fixed" cellSpacing=0 width="100%" cellpading="0">
<TBODY>
<TR>
<TD class="BorderTop BorderBottom BorderLeft" height=55 width="100%" align=center>
<DIV><SPAN id=0>Import</SPAN></DIV>
<DIV align=center valign="middle">
<DIV style="PADDING-BOTTOM: 2px; PADDING-TOP: 2px"><IMG id=0 src="x"><IMG id=0 src="xx">

<IMG id=1 src="x3"> <---Arrow Element Here

</DIV></DIV></TD></TR></TBODY></TABLE></TD>
```

The problem I saw with creating a action builder was that it doesn't behave exactly like a mouse cursor so when you hover over the area it doesn't see it because there are no elements being hovered over it. Though I have not tried this extensively yet. Maybe I could try manually changing the mouse cursor location and than "click" but this is probably an ugly way to do things so I will wait to try it.

If all this fails I will have to end up going directly to the DB which I don't want to do.

Comment: I ended up using Cursor movements and Mouse events which ended up working. Its ugly  but I am not trying to test the page just gain access to its controls.

Answer (score 2):

> when I select the popup link it opens in a new frame on the same page.

For webdriver, you have to explicitly move the driver to a new frame. If you can identify the frame, you can use `driver.switchTo().frame()` to find elements inside it.

Does that help?